# NoClassDefFoundError: com/das/dbmodule/xychart when plotting a graph with Jfree

Tags: java, netbeans, jfreechart

I am developing a web application using NetBeans and MySQL as the database. I am a beginner in Jfree and Java. I created one Java file `xychart.java` in which I am trying to plot XY graph using the Jfree libraries. But I am getting the following exception when I run it :

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/das/dbmodule/xychart
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.das.dbmodule.xychart
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

    Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Your application can't find the compiled `xychart` class file. Simple as that. Did you compile it? Is it on the classpath?

Comment: i am using netbeans. i never compiled any files. i jsut directly run it.

Comment: Looking at this question and the ones previously asked by you, I think need a lot of programming tutorials before you start writing codes of this sort. Please refer to google for the same

Comment: @Saradru Ciswas sir your right. I am just a student. I am learing java. I am doing my final year project. And i am facing many problems.

Comment: When i run xychart.java file , the class file that is xychart.class is not getting generated

Comment: for some time it was working fine but it between it started giving this message. I run my file through command prompt and it worked. I guess there is some problem with netbeans . Is there anyone to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be 3 reasons
1) Class is not available in Java Classpath.
2) You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
3) Any startup script is overriding Classpath environment variable.

Comment: yes sir you are right class file is not getting generated when i run file. can you please help me